# Tkinter connection to display :0 broken

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

Whenever I enter anything in tkinter, it pops up as this error:.

```
X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

The code I am using has nothing wrong with it as I pulled it from the internet and its pretty simple.

```
import tkinter as tk # Python 3.x Version
#import Tkinter as tk # Python 2.x Version

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!") # Create a text label
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20) # Pack it into the window

root.mainloop()
```

and when I try and run the program more than once it pops up with this:

```
  File "/home/~~myname~~/midway.py", line 4, in <module>
    root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

I was wondering if anyone can tell me why it isnt working?

Comment: The "display:0" is the default display on Linux Systems running X11 or Wayland - as for other BSD variants. If yo are using any other Linux graphical application, it should indeed work. However fi your are working on a virtual machine, docker or Windows environment with WSL for which no graphic access is configured for the Linux apps, it won't work.

Comment: In other words: please edit your question to enter the full environment you are using: which Linux, which terminal, and which host OS if any.